# I can alert a variable but javascript console say it is undefined

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var array = new Array(new Array("aa","bb","cc"),new Array("aaa","bbb","ccc"),new Array("aaaa","bbbb","cccc"));

for(var i = 0 ; i <= array.length ; i++) {
    window['dynamic'+i] = array[i];
}



var array2;
var array2val1;
var array2val2;
for(var j=0 ; j<=array.length ; j++) {
    array2 = window['dynamic'+j];
    array2val1 = array2[0];
    array2val2 = array2[1];
    alert(array2val2);
}

</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I can alert array2val1 and array2val2 but in javascript console they are undefined . What is wrong with them ?

Thanks

Comment: `window['dynamic3']` will always be `undefined`. Fix your iteration condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <= array.length ; i++) {
    window['dynamic'+i] = array[i];
    console.log(window['dynamic'+i])
}
```

Here in the above iteration, `i <= array.length` tends to create a `undefined`  and push it to `window['dynamic'+i]`

**Explanation:**

total array length is 3, whereas in iteration you have

```
i=0,
i=1,
i=2,
i=3  // no element exists so undefined is pushed to `window['dynamic'+i]`
```

Same thing here `j<=array.length`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/UpR7j/)

Answer (score 1):

All actually works fine except for a minor error, see http://jsfiddle.net/Z4QGG/

You need to replace

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <= array.length ; i++) { ... }
```

with

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) { ... }
```

and

```
for(var j = 0 ; j <= array.length ; j++) { ... }
```

with

```
for(var j = 0 ; j < array.length ; j++) { ... }
```

If you don't, you end up out of the bounds of your `array` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Change `<=` to `<` because your loop iteration tends to create a undefined and pushing it to window['dynamic'+i] that the reason you are getting undefined.